# solving N Queens using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

below is my code and I don't know where I got wrong 
It compiled well works well but, doesn't print the right result;;; 
if N is 4 , the result should be
2 4 1 3
However, It printed 
1 3 0 0

I guess there are something wrong in for-loop because when I do it with another value like 5 it also printed only two numbers 
this is the result from N=5;
1 4 0 0 0

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NQueens{
    public static int N ;
    public static int [] cols;

    public static void printcols(){
        for(int i =1; i<=N; i++){
            System.out.print(cols[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    public static boolean promising(int level){
        for(int i =1; i<level ; i++){
            if(cols[i] == cols[level]){
                return false;
            }else if(level-i == Math.abs(cols[level]- cols[i]))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean queens(int level){
        if(!promising(level)){
            printcols();
            return false;
        }
        else if(level == N){
            printcols();
            return true;
        }
        for(int i =1; i<N; i++){
            cols[level+1] = i;
            if(queens(level+1)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        N = sc.nextInt();
        cols = new int [N+1];
        queens(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It does not just print `1 3 0 0`, but prints every backtracking step, and at the end it doesn't find any solutions. The problem is that you are mixing 0-based and 1-based indices, and eventually made an error.

In the following line:

```
for(int i =1; i<N; i++){
```

you are iterating over only `N-1` possibilities, leaving `i == N` out. So the fix is just to allow equality too:

```
for(int i =1; i<=N; i++){
```

With this modification the program works as intended.